# Maclaurin Series of $g(x)\cdot f(x)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$f(x)$, $g(x)$ Differentiable infinite amount of times when $x=0$.
The Maclaurin Series of $f(x)$ is:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$$
The Maclaurin Series of $g(x)$ is:
$$\sum_{i=0}^n b_ix^i$$

Need to prove that the Maclaurin Series of $(f\cdot g)(x)$ is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\sum_{j=0}^i a_{i-j}b_i\right)x^i$$

Edit:
Tried to solve it, but go a little bit different result:

$P_n(0) = \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(f\cdot g)(x)}{i!}x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(\sum_{j=0}^i\binom{i}{j} g^{(j)}(x) \cdot f^{(i-j)}(x))}{i!}x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(\sum_{j=0}^i\frac{i!}{j!(i-j)!} g^{(j)}(x) \cdot f^{(i-j)}(x))}{i!}x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n(\sum_{j=0}^i\frac{1}{j!(i-j)!} g^{(j)}(x) \cdot f^{(i-j)}(x))x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n(\sum_{j=0}^i\frac{1}{j!(i-j)!} b_jx^j\cdot i! \cdot a_{i-j}x^{i-j}\cdot (i-j)!)x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n(\sum_{j=0}^i b_jx^j \cdot \frac{a_{i-j}x^i}{x^j})x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n(\sum_{j=0}^i b_j \cdot a_{i-j}x^i)x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n(x^i\cdot \sum_{j=0}^i b_j \cdot a_{i-j})x^i = \sum_{i=0}^n(\sum_{j=0}^i b_j \cdot a_{i-j})x^{2i}$

Comment: Those aren't series, they're polynomials.

Comment: I used the term from wikipedia and it says "series" for some reason:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series

Comment: Anyway, I'm not so familiar with the English math terms, and I would appreciate if you could help me with formulating the question.
@GFauxPas

Comment: @AlexWeitz You should replace all the $n$'s (the upper bound of summation) with $\infty$ and the question will be all right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: start with the definition of the Maclaurin series:

$$P(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ (f \cdot g)^{(n)}(0) }{n!} \cdot x^n$$

and use the formula

$$(f \cdot g)^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(k)}(x) \cdot g^{(n-k)}(x).$$

Comment: I did it, but got to a little bit different result. Instead of x^n, i got x^2n

Comment: @AlexWeitz How?

Comment: Added my attempt to the body of the question.

Comment: @AlexWeitz You seem to have replaced $g^{(j)}(0)$ with $b_j x^j \cdot j!$ and $f^{(i-j)}(0)$ with $a_{i-j} x^{i-j} \cdot (i-j)!$ (not counting minor errors). This is the mistake, because $b_j = \frac{g^{(j)}(0)}{j!}$, so $g^{(j)}(0) = b_j \cdot j!$ and similarly $f^{(i-j)}(0) = a_{i-j} \cdot (i-j)!$. If you don't see why, I will put the solution into my answer tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, right!!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the maclaurin series of $(f\cdot g)(x)$ by
\begin{align*}
(f\cdot g)(x)=\sum_i c_i x^i
\end{align*}
So we have
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_i a_ix^i\right)\left(\sum_j b_jx^j\right)=\sum_n c_nx^n
\end{align*}
But we have
\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_i a_ix^i\right)\left(\sum_j b_jx^j\right)=\sum_i\sum_j a_ib_jx^{i+j}=\sum_n c_nx^n
\end{align*}
So now if we collect all terms on the left hand side with a power of $x^n$, then we get $j=n-i$ so in particular
\begin{align*}
c_n=\sum_{i,j,i+j=n}a_ib_j=\sum_{i=0}^na_ib_{n-i}
\end{align*}

Comment: This is definitely wrong. We only know that $\displaystyle \sum_{i} a_i x^i$ is the Maclaurin series for $f$, but we don't know it converges to $f$. In other words, $f$ need not be analytic.